# Why is Server 2012 assigning "169.254.*.*" series when creating DHCP server?

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2012

I have a small office, with ATT Motorola modem (192.168.1.254) set as passthrough to
Dlink DIR-815 (LAN 192.168.0.1)
I am trying to setup DHCP server on Server 2012, and when I create new DHCP server, the title is created as 169.254.**.**  instead of the domain name.  (Domain clients can retrieve IP's as defined in the scope)

Non-domain clients are not receiving IP's from the server but rather the Motorola...
How do I assure DHCP setup is properly creating itself, and how do I make sure domain and non-domain clients get IP's from the server?

Comment: Is the Motorola configured as a DHCP server by AT&T?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant disable the DHCP. No option. I thought passthrough was only suppose to act like a modem...

Comment: My 2012 server was listing its 169.xx as the DHCP server even when a legitimate scope on another subnet was functioning. I disabled the unused NIC and the server then displayed the correct address. In my case it was more annoying than disruptive but it resolved the problem.

Comment: If you came here like I did from google for `why does my wi-fi/ethernet connect me to 169.254.196.198` see https://superuser.com/questions/610474/keep-getting-invalid-ip-via-wifi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure those 169.254 address are being assigned via DHCP by the modem? Those aren't private subnet addresses, they're [link local autoconfig addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/169.254). They're supposed to be used by hosts that don't have a static IP and can't reach a DHCP server to get an authoritative address.

I would guess that your DHCP service isn't working and that the hosts are configuring themselves with that address range.

If those are Windows hosts, does `ipconfig /renew` return immediately with success or does it time out?

Comment: Let me elaborate a little bit. 2012 server has static ip set, when I go to "Create" the DHCP service/server, and where in previous version of server like 2008, and 2003, the title of the server is the server domain name. In this instance, instead of the domain name, it is given the name in address form as I said, 169.254. whatever

Comment: Does the server have more than one interface? Could it be pulling an autoconfig address from an unexpected interface?

Comment: no, only one interface active...

Comment: *facepalm*   I did not have other interfaced diabled, therefore binding caused the autconfig... Thanks Chris :-)

Comment: No problem, we've all been there :)

Comment: Im afraid Im a little lost on the first half of the question regarding the hardware setup. Wifi clients are reciving IP's from the modem, LAN clients do recieve IP's from the server... Would the wireless solution require bridging to properly receive IP's from the server, in place of the current setup?

Comment: Yes, generally would just bridge the two networks so that the UDP broadcasts that a DHCP client uses to contact the DHCP server will cross to the server you want to use. There should only be one DHCP server on a particular subnet (unless you're doing something special like clustering).

Answer (score 2):

1) The DLink is supplying DHCP. No way in hell it comes from the Motorola or the provider, as the DLink is doing NAT (otherwise it wouldn't have 192.168.0.1 on the LAN side).
Disable DHCP on the DLink please.

2) An exact split between server and other DHCP server for domain and non-domain clients is bogus. When there are 2 DHCP servers both will reply to a DHCP request. The client will decide which offer to accept. If the client had history with one of them it will usually accept the offer of the server it most recently talked to. This may appear as if the domain-clientonly talk to the 2012 server, but that is not really what is happening.

My best guess: The 2012 server originally didn't get DHCP and auto-generated the address. DHCP server on the machine was made active at that moment. Afterwards you set the static IP, but you didn't restart the DHCP service so it didn't pick up on that. It will probably will look normal after a reboot of the server.

Comment: DHCP is disabled on DLINK. 0.1 is the schema for dlink, 1.1 is the schema for modem. Wireless devices are receiving 1.1 addresses...
1.1 is not setup anywhere except the modem.

Comment: further examination, shows my phone getting ip from server. I will look to see if the other wireless devices is looking at history for its ip...

Comment: @Seth So the Motorola is acting as a NAT router, with DHCP and the DLink is passing that through it's own NAT. Which is strange as NAT devices usually filter out DHCP requests unless they are configured as DHCP-relay at the same time (not available in DLinks the last time I looked). If you can't disable DHCP on the Moto you might be able to break the DHCP traversal in the DLink by setting up port-forwarding (in the DLink) of ports 67 and 68 UDP to an unused ip-address. I'm not sure if that would work, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The first reason that causes such problems is this still a network card that is connected. Even if no physical connection, it receives IP 169.254.xx series and can cause such problems. As a solution you can disable IPv4 to this network card. Or you can delete this address using netsh (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731521(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_deleteaddress)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have more than one network adapters on the server, but are not connected? Disabling the not connected network adapters solves this issue. The DHCP server was bound to the wrong adapter.

Comment: This answer does not add any useful information to the years-old other answers.